# Data transfer among different SharePoint sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to move complete SharePoint site content to another SharePoint site? If Yes how it can be done?

Comment: by site, you mean SPSite or SPWeb?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods that come to mind for moving data between sites

- Using a third party solution which does all of the hard work for you, i.e. Axceler's ControlPoint
- Save a list or library as a template, including its content, and then take the template over to the new site.
- If you're looking to move an entire site or web, you can backup/restore or export/import via PowerShell
- Write a custom solution that moves the data per list/item

HTH